# Iterate through style data with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can access my CSS with JQuery like so:

```
alert($(".sliver1").css('width'));
```

The console reports that the .css property of "this" is undefined:

```
var sliver = "sliver";

        $("section").each(function()
        {
            if(this.className.indexOf(sliver) !== -1)
            {
                alert(this.css('width'));
            }
        });
```

How can I access the CSS of the elements found?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery's `.css` wrong. Use this:

```
$("section").css('width');
```

Drop the `;` when inside an `alert()`. Change the property `width` as needed.

When using `.each()`, you need to the jQuery selector `$(this)` for `.css('width')` because `.css()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: Hmmm... It's still alerting undefined. Console is saying whatever "this" is, it doesn't have a CSS property. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try $(this).css('width'); that should work.